# How do I reposition a datepiciker's dropdown to be above the input form?

Tags: javascript, css

Is there a simple CSS/JS way to do this i.e. not trying to figure out how much space is left, but simply "switching it up"?

I tried using negative margins, but it didn't cooperate.

Here is the [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/pedantic-haslett-p0pko).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try making your popup absolute and your container as relative.  In your case, the `.input-group` will be the container and the `#datepicker` is the popup:

You can add this to your css:

```
.input-group {
  position: relative;
}

#datepicker {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 25px;  // Adjust as needed
}
```

Working sandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/damp-haze-fq21z